# Errors when trying to install deb package

Tags: debian, installation, failed-installation, dpkg

I have tried to install the following deb package, but it keeps failing and I'm not sure how to fix.

Below is the output following unsuccessful reattempts.

## Failed installation

`sudo dpkg -i particl-desktop-2.3.3-linux-amd64.deb`

```
(Reading database ... 650733 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack particl-desktop-2.3.3-linux-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking particl-desktop (2.3.3) over (2.3.3) ...
Setting up particl-desktop (2.3.3) ...
Could not parse file "/usr/share/applications/screensavers/glitchpeg.desktop": Key file contains line ?several times a second.  After a while, finds a new image to corrupt. Written by Jamie Zawinski; 2018.? which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment
Could not parse file "/usr/share/applications/byobu.desktop": No such file or directory
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.62) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
gtk-update-icon-cache: The generated cache was invalid.
WARNING: icon cache generation failed
```

## Further information

```
uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2 (2020-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo cat /var/log/dpkg.log
2020-05-18 11:36:06 status installed particl-desktop:amd64 2.3.3
2020-05-18 11:36:06 trigproc desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-4 <none>
2020-05-18 11:36:06 status half-configured desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-4
2020-05-18 11:36:06 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-4
2020-05-18 11:36:06 trigproc mime-support:all 3.62 <none>
2020-05-18 11:36:06 status half-configured mime-support:all 3.62
2020-05-18 11:36:07 status installed mime-support:all 3.62
2020-05-18 11:36:07 trigproc hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2 <none>
2020-05-18 11:36:07 status half-configured hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2
2020-05-18 11:36:07 status installed hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2

sudo dpkg -l | grep particl
ii  particl-desktop                        2.3.3                                amd64
```

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a minor problem with the screensaver *glitchpeg*, but there is no need to remove it.

**vim /usr/share/applications/screensavers/glitchpeg.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Glitchpeg
Exec=/usr/lib/xscreensaver/glitchpeg -root
TryExec=/usr/lib/xscreensaver/glitchpeg
Comment=Loads an image, corrupts it, and then displays the corrupted version,
several times a second.  After a while, finds a new image to corrupt. Written by Jamie Zawinski; 2018
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Screensaver;
OnlyShowIn=MATE;
```

Note that Jamie throws a semicolon in as punctuation before "2018", but I am guessing that it messes up the parser.  I removed the semicolon and the error went away.  Careless Jamie!

Comment: At least he was nice enough to put his name on it XD

Comment: I removed the semicolon but this did not solve the problem. I put the `comment` entry on the same line (ie removed the carriage return from this entry) and then it worked without displaying any problem. 
IMHO editors automatic formatters may have something to do with this problem.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not the semicolon. The line that offends the parser is the second part of the "Comment" field. Remove the extra line feeds in that key=value pair and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/screensavers/glitchpeg.desktop
```

did the trick for me. was trying to install Zoom on Lubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue we just need to remove the broken line with the text:

> ***several times a second.  After a while, finds a new image to corrupt. Written by Jamie Zawinski; 2018***

Let all comment in the same line:

> **Comment=Loads an image, corrupts it, and then displays the corrupted version, several times a second.  After a while, finds a new image to corrupt. Written by Jamie Zawinski 2018.**

And its solved.

Answer (score 0):

could not parse file "/usr/share/applications/screensavers/glitchpeg.desktop": Key file contains line ?several times a second.  After a while, finds a new image to corrupt. Written by Jamie Zawinski; 2018.? which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).